# HTTP.Get - Need a solution for Non english xml data

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I am using

Server side javascript 'HTTP.Get' to retrieve Meta editor XML data. I could successfully retrieve for English documents into Salesforce Marketing Cloud.

But It doesn't work for Chinese and Japanese languages.
The result looks like 'ã‚¤ãƒ³ãƒ“ã‚¶ã'

Is there a solution to get the result correctly? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to set the content-type within the header. [SSJS article](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_httpGet.htm)

> Marketing Cloud recognizes any character set returned in the HTTP headers via Content-Type. For example, you can use a UTF-8 encoded HTML file with Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 included in the header. If the encoding is not specified in the header, the application assumes all returned data will be in the character set WindowsCodePage 1252.

[Ampscript Dev Docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/httpget.htm)

Comment: Thanks for update. I tried with 
var headerNames = ["Authorization","Content-Type","charset"];       
var headerValues = [SFtoken,"text/xml","utf-8"];     

Content-Type as "application/octet-stream" and "html/text" as well as the response in XML but not working.  I am using this script in Marketing cloud cloud page.

Answer (score 1):

I raised a ticket in SFMC support. Its been fixed by support as they updated the settings to utf-8 at the backend. Thanks